# Disabling the ToolBar overlay Effect and List scroll disable

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar, transparent

Problem 1:
I have made my toolbar transparent but There is some sort of overlay effect which I don't want. How can I remove that effect? I have marked that place(1) in a sample image.

> code for ToolBar:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/cvSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

> ToolBarLayOut:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:background="@color/transparent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
 >

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/location_ic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_location"
  />
<TextView
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/location_ic"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
    android:padding="6dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fontFamily="@font/custom_font"
    android:text="서울 서초구 강남역 주변"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/toolbar_title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Problem 2: I am using a scroll view with a child list view in my app. but the problem is when I am taping any white space(marked 2) o list item parent scroll is not working but when taping on images then the parent scroll works (Marked 3). only the child list view scroll is working which I don't want I want the parent scroll to work here.

[image]

Comment: For problem 1: remove appbarlayout use toolbar without it. as AppBarLayout adding shadow.

Answer (score 1):

AppBarLayout has StateListAnimator by default try setting it to null using below code

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/cvSlider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:stateListAnimator="@null"
            app:theme="@style/CustomActionBar"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <include layout="@layout/toolbar_layout" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: if you are not using appbarlayout can you try using standalone toolbar.

Comment: if you can check by removing theme that you have applied, that might be overriding some values.